# Inverse participation ratio (IPR) literature

Tags: quantum-information, resource-recommendations, anderson-localization

I am curently working with the [inverse participation ratio (IPR)](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=inverse+participation+ratio) as a measure of localization but I can't find literature that just explains why and how exactly it relates to localization. I get the intuition but I would love to have a paper that just introduces the inverse participation ratio in a mathematical way (especially on how it relates to localization length).